# UITableView w/ translucent section headers & different colored section backgrounds

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview

I'm trying to set up a UITableView with elements layered like this:

[image: diagram]

Specifically, the table has multiple sections and each section has a different background color. To do this I would normally just modify each cell. The tough part is that I'd like the section headers to be translucent. When I do this, the background under the header is the table view's background color when there's no cell under the header. I could of course set the table view's background color, but then the color under each header would be the same.

How would I create a table view like that depicted in the diagram?

UPDATE: To make it absolutely clear, I know how to make a custom header view, and know how to make it translucent using the alpha property. The problem is with what is UNDER the view. I need what is underneath to be the section's background color, not the table view's background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no exact framework provided solution for this but we can make use `backgroundView` property. Set it to a scroll view. This scroll view will contain background views for section. Define yourself as observer for the table view's `contentSize` and `contentOffset` and alter the scroll view's values parallel to table view's. Get the frame rects for your background views using `rectForSection:` method and create subviews to the scroll view with appropriate background colors set. This should work to an extent.

The problem with this approach is that that the scroll view will remain static when the table view bounces on the edges. Then there is the case of getting the cell to blend well with this background.

Comment: That's a creative solution. I will play around to see what I can make of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use a UIImageView in the header and use a (custom) image.

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section           {

      UIView * junkView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"headerImageBackground.png"]];
      junkView.alpha = .3;
      [junkView autorelease];
      return junkView;
 }
```

Comment: Wouldn't putting an image view under the header obscure the cells that pass underneath it? That would defeat the reason why they're translucent in the first place… Or am I missing something?

Comment: Ah, ok I played around with it a bit. If you put an imageView in the header, you might need to play with it's .alpha property to get the effect you want.  see edited answer.

Comment: thumsup for the naming!